# Sails.js query db by foreign key

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

I'm wondering how to make a query by foreign key using the default Waterline model.

I have two models Post and Category - Post has a foreign key category. I need to make a query like so:

```
Post.find({
  where: {
    category: query
  }
}).exec(function (err, data) {});
```

In this case `query` is a string so the results returned should be Posts containing searched category.

What is the best way to do this?

*Note: Current example does not work*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured how to implement this using the category id:

```
Category.find().where({ name: query }).exec(function (error, categories) {
   var catArr = [];

   if (categories.length) {
     categories.map(function (item) {
       catArr.push(item.id);
     });
   }

   Post.find().where({ category: catArr }).exec(function (error, posts) {
     // do stuff
   });

});
```

Also had to add attributes in the models like so:

```
// Post
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
       type: 'string'
    },
    category: {
       model: 'category'
    }
  }
};

// Category
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
       type: 'string'
    },
    post: {
       model: 'post'
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Your model should be

```
// Post
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
       type: 'string'
    },
    category: {
       model: 'category'
    }
  }
};

// Category
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
       type: 'string'
    },
    post: {
       collection: 'Post',
       via: 'category'
    }
  }
};
```

Then query from category would be

```
Category
    .find()
    .where({ name: query })
    .populateAll()
    .exec(function (error, categories) {
       var catArr = [];

       if (categories.length) {
         categories.map(function (item) {
           catArr.push(item.id);
         });
       }

       Post.find().where({ category: catArr }).exec(function (error, posts) {
         // do stuff
       });

    });
```

Or simply you can query it from `post` by

```
Post
    .find()
    .where({ category: categoryId })
    .populateAll()
    .exec(function (error, posts) {
       // posts is all post with category that defined
    });
```

Make sure that you know `categoryId` if you want to query it from `post`. I usually use `categoryId` is `string` and slugify from `name`, so I can query category by it's name and make sure that category name (and also ID of course) is unique.

Comment: Great solution but I have additional parameters when making the query for Post (and don't know the category id) so I'm using the solution mentioned in my answer - Also because Post-Category has one-one association I'm using only model: 'category'/ model: 'post' in my models (according to the documentation).

Comment: It's achievable, but before I give a solution for that, why `category` is not included in your `Post` attributes? Because one-one relation (in NoSQL actually) is better served in it's main fields. Enumeration can be achieve by `enum`.

Comment: I'm aware of this but categories should be dynamic (inserted/modified by user). That is why ```enum``` is not an option. If you look at my solution you'll notice  that ```category``` is included as an attribute in the ```Post``` model.

Comment: It makes sense for a category to have many posts under it. I am curious why would you make a one-to-one relationship between category and post?